# VB.NET - Stream Reader/Writer Alternative?

Tags: vb.net, save

I am working on a **Customer relationship management** software (CRM) and am using **lists** to store all the information read out of an excel (CSV) file. I would like to **edit** some information in my custom CRM and was curious if there is maybe a better way of saving the information than just writing it all in a textfile and having to read it all again on the next startup?

thanks in advance

Comment: I've used OLEDB to interact with text files. If you save it as native Excel, I know you can interact with it as if you're working with a database.

Comment: You could use the Excel ACE or JET data provider to a CSV and use the textfile as a database.

Comment: If you don't want to use a database, such as SQL Express, you could at least save the data to an XML file rather than a CSV file.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am fairly new to VB.NET, I have not yet worked with databases or whatsoever, What advantage do I have saving the data to an XML file? 

Additionally, I am using a stream reader at the moment and am experiencing an unknown behavior:

`Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(aFile,Encoding.Default)
Do While reader.Peek() <> -1  
If Not (reader.ReadLine = "") Then CustomFile.Add(reader.ReadLine)  
Loop  
reader.Close()`

if I read out my List(CustomFile) then I only see an empty string, which is what I am trying to avoid.